# What use does the predictor stage in a particle filter have?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, genetic-algorithms, monte-carlo, filtering-problem

Im a bit confused about the [particle filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter).
I understand the generic particle filter algorithm but in some literature say particle filter has predictor stage which is not mentioned in the generic particle filter.

I thought it weighed the particle based on observation. What's the predictor stage used for?

Comment: Upon first reading, I thought were talking about car parts.